# What kind of birds?

Tags: riddle, enigmatic-puzzle

Seek out a sunny picture -
Remember you're on SE -
And on that sunny picture,
Figure out what you can;
You are a less capital idea
Than those who follow you.

**What kind of birds appear?**

Hint 1:

> When you're on SE, where would you find a picture?

Hint 2:

> Your answer can take the form of an actual picture (which has birds in). The challenge is to find the correct picture, not to identify the birds.

Hint 3 (like Hint 1, but bigger):

> When you upload a picture while making a post on SE, where will the URL of that picture be?

Comment: @mmking Nope, I'm afraid not. Thinking of adding a hint soon, but if you're having a serious go at it, I'll hold off for a while longer.

Comment: Bird of Prey...?

Comment: Hmm, someone's profile picture? But then how could you be sure they didn't change it and so ruin the puzzle?

Comment: @Pete It's not someone's profile picture (although it *is* personally related to another SE user, but you don't need to know that to solve the puzzle).

Comment: I say eagles, because I was roaming around SE and ended up on a lotr question arguing about eagles.

Comment: @Spacemonkey Not [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/75862/who-was-the-fifth-army-in-the-hobbit-the-battle-of-the-five-armies-movie/75873#75873) by any chance? :-) I think I'm gonna post a hint soon...

Comment: Am I at a disadvantage because I'm using the SE iphone app?

Comment: If you don't need to actually identify the specific birds, then the [cycling SE site](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/) has a sunny picture with birds. Though can't link that to "a less capital idea" or "those who follow"... (unless it's just that the birds are following the cyclist).

Comment: @Alconja It's possible to identify the birds; it's just that that's not the real point of the puzzle.

Comment: Do the last two lines have to do with the imgur id?

Comment: @mmking You're thinking along the right lines...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> [image: skelemingos]

Seek out a sunny picture -
Remember you're on SE -

> The url for pictures uploaded on SE is https://i.stack.imgur.com. You would need the ID to identify the picture.

And on that sunny picture,
Figure out what you can;

> The ID has 5 letters/digits. It has something to do with "sunny".
>  The closest thing to turning "sunny" into figures (figure out) is turning "s" into 5.

You are a less capital idea
Than those who follow you.

> u (you) is uncapitalized. The letters that follow are capital. So we get that the last few letters are "uNNY".

Put that together. The url for the picture is

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uNNY.jpg

**What kind of birds appear?**

> Skelemingos!

Comment: Excellent job! This is the correct solution. Could you explain "Figure out what you can" a bit more fully, to show why it's 5uNNY rather than suNNY or SuNNY?

Comment: I'm not really sure of that, to be honest.

Comment: "Figure out" means take the word "sunny" and turn as much of it as you can into _figures_, i.e. S -> 5. The rest of it is all letters, with lower-case and capitalisation determined by the final 2 lines.

Comment: Okay, got it. Time to edit...

Comment: You have no idea how thrilled and flattered I am to have my flock of skelemingos be the subject of a SE puzzle! How wonderful :D

Answer (score 6):

> Seek out a sunny picture -
>   Remember you're on SE -

The ["page not found" page](http://stackexchange.com/pagenotfound) of Stack Exchange has a sunny picture.

[image]

> And on that sunny picture,
>   Figure out what you can;

The image's name is "no-pandas-here.jpg". Pandas are likely to become extinct.

> You are a less capital idea
>   Than those who follow you.

We're looking for an "idea" that can restore a species to a stable population.
If we interpret "capital" as "involving punishment by death", then *Jurassic Park* comes to mind - people clone dinosaurs, and are killed by their own creations.
So the idea is **cloning**. Although it is quite capital, it is still a "less capital idea" than "cloning *and* genetically engineering hybrid animals to make them more cunning and vicious", as (probably) seen in *Jurassic World*, which "follows" the original film (i.e. is a sequel).

> What kind of birds appear?

According to Wikipedia's [De-extinction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De-extinction) page, the potential candidate birds for cloning are:

- Passenger pigeon
- Carolina parakeet
- Ivory-billed woodpecker
- Moa
- Heath hen
- Dodo

Comment: You start off quite nicely (though incorrectly), but your interpretation of lines 5-6 looks very dodgy. PS: well done on escaping the labyrinth! ;-)

Comment: Thanks. Yep, I felt good about the 404 page but after that it felt like pounding a square peg into a round hole :-) Doesn't hurt to try, though.

Answer (score 5):

The bird is

> Larry Bird

Seek out a sunny picture -
Remember you're on SE -

> This is the button in the answer box to add a photo.

And on that sunny picture,
Figure out what you can;

> Click the `?` to get more help

You are a less capital idea
Than those who follow you.

> `advanced help` is in all lowercase letters, but the rest of the options are capitalized. If you go to the advanced help link, you can find this section mid page:
>
> Need More Detail?
>
> Visit the [official Markdown syntax reference page](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax).
>
>
> The linked page contains a dummy link to search for Larry Bird images.

Comment: +1; you're the closest so far. But why "sunny"? Sunny is in some ways the most important clue. Also, check the second hint.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I will try :

To begin I searched for a sunny picture in SE, I went looking for it in

> The photography SE, and especially the Hall of Fame

then naturally here

> https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4659/image-of-the-week-hall-of-fame-2014-archive

But once I was here I needed a 'sunny picture' and there were many of them.

But one picture got my attention

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Cj0T.jpg

Because it was posted by :

> Riot

And I think it is somehow related to "You are a less capital idea
Than those who follow you.", and of course it is a picture of a bird.

I don't think that it is the right answer, especially because of my lack of sun in my answer, but I hope I have helped in some ways .

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't figure out how to 'spoilerize' link.

Comment: Nice; I thought somebody would try Photography.SE. Unfortunately it's not right. Where would you find a picture when you're on ***any*** SE?

Answer (score 0):

**Area 51** Icon looks like **sunny**, and remove (**less**) the Capital and take the following letters to get **rea**.

**Area 51** background is a moon with a few aliens in **flight**.

So couple all this with **Bird** to get **Rhea** [ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhea_%28bird%29 ] which is a **flightless bird** (refer : flight + less )

[[ It seems ambiguous, but this is the best I got till now ]]

Comment: Almost all of this is barking up the wrong tree, I'm afraid. Check the first hint...